# Shared Preferences issue, not freeing the value after calling clear

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application I want to clear `SharedPreferences` on button click. This is what I'm using for storing values in it:

```
SharedPreferences clearNotificationSP = getSharedPreferences("notification_prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor Notificationeditor = clearNotificationSP.edit();
Notificationeditor.putString("notificationCount", notificationCountValue);
Notificationeditor.commit();
```

And the following code on onClick():

```
SharedPreferences clearedNotificationSP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editorSP = clearedNotificationSP.edit();
editorSP.remove("notificationCount");
editorSP.commit();

System.out.println("Saved in SP clearedNotification: "+ clearNotification);
```

I was printing the value after clearing it but still I was getting the same value.

What am I missing?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDefaultSharedPreferences` and  `getSharedPreferences("notification_prefs", );`

returns two different `SharedPreferences`. Since you are adding `notificationCount` inside `notification_prefs`, you should retrieve SharedPreference with `getSharedPreferences("notification_prefs", );`

`getDefaultSharedPreferences` uses a default preference-file name, while getSharedPreferences use the filename you provided as paramter

Comment: How you suggest I could do that?

Comment: use always the same file. getSharedPreferences("notification_prefs", 0); is good

Comment: I have made edit like this. `clearedNotificationSP = getSharedPreferences("notification_prefs", 0);` while I'm clearing it. Is that right?

Comment: SharedPreferences clearedNotificationSP = getSharedPreferences("notification_prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editorSP = clearedNotificationSP.edit();
editorSP.remove("notificationCount");
editorSP.commit();

Comment: But still I'm getting value, after clearing it. `System.out.println("Saved in SP clearedNotification: "+ clearNotification);` This line is printing the value, why this is not giving me `0` instead if I'm clearing the value.

Comment: I do not understand. Where do  you read the value of clearNotification ?

Comment: Because I just want to check here. And also when I switch from activity there also I'm getting the value from here. I'm checking UI updates through this SP.

Comment: I understand you want to read there but do you store in clearNotification the value of notificationCount that SharedPreference holds?

Comment: Yes, I'm storing that, you can see my question for checking that.

Comment: I see but at some point you should do something like clearNotification = clearNotificationSP.getString("notificationCount", ""); or am I wrong?